# Ruby. How does string interpolation work with to_s method

Tags: ruby

I don't understand how does string interpolation work in Ruby. I know that when I use curly braces `#{}` the interpreter calls `.to_s` method on the object. For ex:

```
class A
end

a = A.new
puts "#{a}"
# #<A:0x00007fbbc8110090>

# Redefine to_s method and return another string
def a.to_s
  '1'
end
puts "#{a}"
# 1
```

If `.to_s` method returns not a string, it works like a magic. It seems like it still calls original `.to_s` method, but how?

```
# Redefine to_s method and return not a string
def a.to_s
  2
end
puts "#{a}"
# As a result it returns result of the original .to_s method
# #<A:0x00007fbbc8110090>
```

Comment: The behavior of string interpolation is specified in section 8.7.6.3.3 *Double quoted strings* of the [ISO/IEC 30170:2012 *Information technology — Programming languages — Ruby* specification](https://iso.org/standard/59579.html). Your question is answered in clause h) of paragraph 11 of the sub-section *Semantics*.

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure if it is helpful to tell an OP that they will find the answer to their question in a document that is behind a paywall and costs about $200...

Comment: _"it works like a magic"_ – it's just a conditional: if the return value is a string then use it, otherwise invoke the original `to_s` method.